# What color should I use for the walls and ceiling of a photography studio?

Tags: studio, studio-setup

What color should I use for the ceilings and walls of a photography studio? How might this differ from a studio used for video?

Comment: What do you want the work done there to look like?

Comment: There are at least a couple slightly different senses of the word "studio" that could apply here. Will the studio's environment (walls, architecture, furniture) be visible in the resulting photos or videos? That is, is the studio itself part of the set or set dressing (think: video podcast studio)? Or is just a shell where all of the sets, dressing, lighting is completely controlled, and nothing appears in the produced work that wasn't specifically set up for the shot?

Answer (score 6):

Neutral, usually black or white depending your needs.

Assuming that your backdrop will be separate (paper roll).

White:
Walls can be used as reflectors. But, can be difficult to control stray reflections when you don't want them.
Bright and cheerful for your subjects.

Black:
Allows more control of light.
Reflectors, if you need them, will need to be separate.
Room may appear creepy to subjects.

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon how you plan to use it:

- Flat black that reflects as little light as possible
- Neutral¹ white that reflects a significant amount of light
- Any neutral¹ shade of gray between the two extremes of black and white

<sub>¹ Neutral: without any color tint added</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Aamir You can show your appreciation by casting an upvote fro the answer. As the original poster, only you can also select one answer as the "accepted" answer.